# All controls stacked on top of each other

Tags: android

I'm just starting to learn how to develop Android apps and when I tried to finally test an app with the emulator, the TextView, ImageView, and Button controls all seem to be stacked on top of each other at the top of the screen. I formatted the controls with the simple drag and drop feature in Android Studio. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using RelativeLayout. Please update your question to share your XML for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Tool you are using is called Layout Editor which is not so great for building layouts actually.
That drag-n-drop creation can cause errors like that and you should probably start from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm)

> Hint: as a parent layout you most probably (in this case) use **LinearLayout** with vertical orientation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for you is to try to follow a tutorial or a course to get a better understand of how the user-interface works in android.
That's might be useful [Android Basics: User-interface](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-interface--ud834)

Good luck!